# Need to avoid users performing any task in a tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, force.com, html

I have two forms developed in two different pages using Lightning Aura bundle in communities.Now,The user opens both the forms in two different tabs in UI.The submit button in both forms are enabled for now. If the user clicks on submit button in form 2(say in Tab 2) then i should disable the submit button in form 1(say in Tab 1).

Now for me, the problem is if the user clicks on submit in tab 2 and comes to tab1 and if he doesn't refresh Tab1 then he still sees submit button of Form 1 to be enabled.if he clicks on button 1 then the business login is affected.

I understand we can put a validation rule or trigger logic in the backend to not to allow the user to submit the form 1 after submiting form 2, but i want to implement this logic in front end.   Please let me know if it is possible to do it using html or Lightning bundle.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be possible using application events. Just search for it. The documentation is great and contains examples.

Don't try or get mixed up with component events: application events is what you need for this requirement.